# jquery select with BlackBerry Torch trackpad

Tags: jquery, blackberry, mobile

I have a jquery mobile website that has simple select.
I have successfully tested it on many devices including the BlackBerry 8520, with a trackpad.
On the BlackBerry torch which has both touch screen and trackpad the list only opens when clicked from the touch screen.  Nothing happens when I try to use the trackpad.
I have other clickable controls on that page that works fine using both the touchscreen and the trackpad.
here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0; maximum-scale=1.0; user-scalable=no;" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery.mobile-1.0a3.min.css" />

<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.5.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.mobile-1.0a3.min.js"></script>

<title></title>
</head>
<body>
<div data-theme="p" data-role="page">
<h1>
    Test Select on Blackberry</h1>
<div >
    <select width="100%" name="subjectList">
        <option value="subject">Subject (please select)</option>
        <option value="subject1">subject 1</option>
        <option value="subject2">subject 2</option>
        <option value="subject3">subject 3</option>
        <option value="subject4">subject 4</option>
        <option value="subject5">subject 5</option>
        <option value="subject6">subject 6</option>
        <option value="subject7">subject 7</option>
        <option value="subject8">subject 8</option>
        <option value="subject9">subject 9</option>
    </select>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Wihout any code, it is going to be complex. I can't even test myself to reproduce the problem.

Comment: it's really just a simple select option list

Comment: even if it's super simple, I don't have the time to code it and test it. So if you can share the code, even if it's 2 line, maybe there is an error in those 2. So post some code, and I'm gonna try to help.

Comment: Hi @Michael B thank you for your time i have added the test code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the solution to the problem 
the issue was with the JQuery mobile JS file when i upgraded it to the latest one the problem was solved

Thanks for your time on this one Michael